# When is it true that $Z(A)^{**} = Z(A^{**})$ for a C*-algebra $A$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

For a (unital) C$^*$-algebra $A$ with centre $Z(A)$ the bidual $A^{**}$ is a von Neumann algebra with centre $Z(A^{**})$ for which I believe that $Z(A)^{**} \subset Z(A^{**})$ holds by extending the product on $A$ to $A^{**}$ and using that it is separately w$^*$-continuous. My question is if there is anything known about when we have an equality $Z(A)^{**} = Z(A^{**})$? This is true for commutative and finite-dimensional C$^*$-algebras, but I can't seem to find anything related to this question in the literature.

For example, is the bidual of $B(H)$ (the bounded operators on a Hilbert space) a factor? If not, this would be an example for which the equality does not hold true.

Please note that I am not an expert in the theory of C$^*$-algebras.

Comment: I don't know a full answer to your question, but it is not true that $Z(A)^{**}=Z(A^{**})$ in general. For example take a C*-algebra $A$ that has trivial center and two inequivalent irreducible representations (for example $B(H)$ or any unital, simple infinite dimensional C*-algebra).  The two inequivalent representations will correspond to orthogonal central projections $p,q\in A^{**}.$  So $Z(A)^{**}$ is trivial in this case while $Z(A^{**})$ is not.  The correspondence between representations of $A$ and projections in $A^{**}$ can be found in many places (e.g. Takesaki I Chap. 3)

Comment: My guess would be that $A$ must be unital, sub-homogeneous (i.e. there exists a natural number $n$ such that every irreducible representation of $A$ has dimension less than or equal to $n$), and have Hausdorff primitive ideal space.